# Magento 2: Dynamically ignore tier price configuration upon add to cart action

Tags: magento2, event-observer, tierprice, subscription

I have modified a product in a way that you can either buy it "as usual" or decide to buy it as a subscription (via custom options). If you decide to buy as subscription tier prices should apply. If not only the regular price should apply.

What I am currently stuck with is how to tell magento to ignore the tier prices if option 1 (regular product) is chosen. Is there any way (observer, plugin etc) to dynamically ignore the tier price configuration when putting a product to cart?

Thank you